# Amadeus Flight Offers API

Tags: amadeus

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 503,
      "title": "No available service for processing the request.",
      "code": 19,
      "source": {
        "pointer": "shopping/flight-offers"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the above error when I call the Flight Offers API (https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=NBO&destination=MBA&departureDate=2018-12-10&adults=1&travelClass=ECONOMY&nonStop=true&currency=KES&max=50)on the Amadeus API Explorer. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

We had a technical issue with the API, it's fixed now.

Sorry for the incovinience

Answer (score 0):

It's not fixed. I am getting the same issue with below message -
This site is briefly unavailable for scheduled daily maintenance. It should take less than 2 minutes. Sorry for the inconvenience.